# Give Bootstrap's collapsed navbar an organized layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a bootstrap navigation bar with images, the problem is that when this collapses it becomes a mess due to some custom margin's and the images running over my text.

Is there any way to specify a new style or layout for when my navbar is collapsed? I would prefer everything to layout like

```
ImageOfHome
Home (text)
ImageOfUsers
Users (text)
ect...
```

Instead it all runs over each other. I also want to remove the hover affect during a collapsed state.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/653/)**

(shrink view for collapsed bar to appear, when you open it you will see how everything is all messy and running over each other in the collapsed vew)

Here is the navbar code

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" style="margin-top:25px">
    <div class="container" style="height:5px">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="margin-bottom:-80px; padding-bottom:-80px">
            <span class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </span>
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "LakerLegends")" style="margin-right:-30px" onclick="return false">
                <img src="/Content/img/LogoConstruction.png" alt="Logo" width="275" height="100" style="margin-top:-25px" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse pull-right">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="text-align:center">
                <li class="rolloverNav">

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "LakerLegends")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/homeNew.png" class="urlImage"/>
                        <br />
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Users")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/usersNew.png" class="urlImage" />
                        <br />
                        Users
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Events")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/eventsNew.png" class="urlImage" />
                        <br />
                        Events
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Competitive")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/competitiveNew.png" class="urlImage"  />
                        <br />
                        Teams
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Streams")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/streamsNew.png" class="urlImage" />
                        <br />
                        Streams
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Staff")" id="navbar">
                        <img src="~/Content/navbar/staff.png" class="urlImage"/>
                        <br />
                        Staff
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my CSS for it

```
.rolloverNav {
    padding-bottom:0px;
}

a#navbar:hover {
    color:#f1fe51;
    margin-top:-10px;
    opacity: 1;
}


a#navbar {
    opacity:1;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
    font-size:14px
}

.urlImage {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Been looking at using `@media` and such, but nothing seems to be affecting the CSS. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few simple changes to get it looking somewhat respectable:

1) Add a bit of margin to your `<li>` elements in your nav.

```
.nav li {
    margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

2) Wrap your hover in a media query that only allows it to run at 768px and higher, so it will not be applied when your menu is collapsed.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    a#navbar:hover {
        color:#f1fe51;
        margin-top:-10px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

[Update JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/654/)

EDIT:

You have a piece of inline styling that is keeping your collapsed menu from dropping below the menu button.

This:

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="margin-bottom:-80px; padding-bottom:-80px">
```

Needs to be this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
```

[New JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/655/)

Comment: I am trying this out, however whatever I wrap within the media does not seem to matter, it applies during un-collapsed as well. If you look at the fiddle, the buttons still sit on the collapsed icon, I want to push them down below that. But when I try to add any margins within that media tag, it margins the entire navbar during un-collapsed as well. That make sense? Look at the fiddle right when it collapses and you will see how "home" is running on top of the navbar icon. Thank you thus far!

Comment: Do you have the viewport meta tag in your header? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` Without that your media queries will not work.

Comment: I believe so, this is in my layout.cshtml `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Is that file included in the file with your menu?

Comment: Just saw the update and that worked just fine! Is there a way to still keep `.navbar-header { margin-bottom:-80px; } `then have it revert to `0px` during collapse? It looks like the `-80px` is trumping the media wrap?

Comment: You can put that CSS inside of the same media query that the hover is in, that way the -80px margin only applies to screen sizes above collapsed. http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/657/

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own CSS to override Bootstraps CSS and use the media queries that Bootstrap also uses which are:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

modified for normal CSS:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @768px) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @992px) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @1200px) { ... }
```

Taken from:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Your jsFiddle is abit messy with images that aren't loaded and such by the way.